# jQuery Slick Slider filtering - get real position on carousel after filtering

Tags: jquery, slick.js

first thing sorry my english.

I have a problem I don't get out of,
after filtering the slick carousel using `slick ('slickFilter', '.nero-altText');`
how do I know the real position of the image that I return?

example

```
<div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable" style="height: 749px;">
    <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; height: 285px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
        <div class="product__thumb-item nero-altText slick-slide" data-index="1" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;"> img code </div>
        <div class="product__thumb-item red-altText slick-slide" data-index="2" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;"> img code </div>
        <div class="product__thumb-item red-altText slick-slide" data-index="3" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;"> img code </div>
        <div class="product__thumb-item nero-altText slick-slide" data-index="4" data-slick-index="4" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;"> img code </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

after filtering i have only

```
<div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable" style="height: 749px;">
    <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; height: 285px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
        <div class="product__thumb-item nero-altText slick-slide" data-index="1" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;"> img code </div>
        <div class="product__thumb-item nero-altText slick-slide" data-index="4" data-slick-index="4" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 80px;"> img code </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

but with

```
var index = $(evt.currentTarget).data('index');
```

the index is not 1,2 but 1,4

i need to have 1,2 also after filtering. is possible?

Thank's

Comment: please share your js code. it's not clear to understand what you have done.for example what's the `altText`

Comment: @jabbar have changed the example...
the code it's very long, the alttext is a string which use for the filter. But this part is ok.. the problem is, if i return the data-index i have 1 and 4, i want to retrieve the filtered position inside carousel, 1,2